# In Codeigniter how to make library wait until view is rendered

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to show a modal when triggered by my custom class library, but without explicity calling any of its methods from outside.

I would have to wait until view template is loaded.

How can I make my library's methods wait until view is loaded?

As first step I have already added my library to the autoload array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try **Hooks**?
Following may work but not sure. Didn't try myself.

```
$hook['post_controller'] = array(
        'class'    => 'MyClass',
        'function' => 'Myfunction',
        'filename' => 'Myclass.php',
        'filepath' => 'hooks',
        'params'   => array('beer', 'wine', 'snacks')
);
```

Reference - https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/hooks.html